# How to log defined log as error exception class in Python

Tags: python, logging, exception

First step:
Besides creating logger I define log format:

```
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s'
```

I have validation and error handling code:

```
class ZipCodeError(Exception):
    "Customized exception for Zip code errors"
    pass

def validate_zip(val):
    try:
        #try to validate
    exception:
        msg = "requires a valid 5-digit US zip code"
        logging.error(msg)
        raise ZipCodeError(msg)
```

If I run code, validation function will raise exception. 
In the log file, funcName (name of function/method containing the logging call) should show error in validate_zip() function. It is OK, but I would love that funcName showed ZipCodeError() as an error, even though the class works fine without any errors.

The question:
Is it possible to log raise of ZipCodeError() as an error in the logfile?

Comment: Why not do it in the `ZipCodeError` class, on `__init__`?

Comment: Won't %(funcName)s log it as __init__ ?